# Chevron Icon pointing up or down depending on accordion position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I've got an accordion I've built using jQuery UI. I need the chevron icons that point up or down depending on if the section is open or closed. The problem is my jQuery. At least initially it is. I'm seeing both chevrons on load and once clicked the chevron doesn't change at all.

Jquery

```
$(function() {

     $(".section a").click(function() {

          $(".chevron").removeClass("chevron").addClass("up");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.chevron {
background: url("images/down.png") no-repeat;
}

.up {
background: url("images/up.png");
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="section">
   <a href="#"><div class="tab active">
   <span class="chevron"></span><h3>Section 1</h3>
   </div></a> <!-- tab -->
```

Comment: Add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if possible.

Comment: I'm confused but the code I put in the jsfiddle has working chevrons. Which I'm guessing are from jquery UI. How come I don't have them on my working copy locally? http://jsfiddle.net/thomasp423/pcf5d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference [this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/) so it toggles the element you are clicking on (not all of them at once).  Once you have `$(this)`, you can use [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to search for the chevron within the link.

Finally, you can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to switch between the class states.  This allows you to click the link repeatedly and have it switch between the class states.

```
$(function() {
    //Add down to all .chevrons
    $(".section a .chevron").addClass('down'); 

    //Toggle up/down classes
    $(".section a").click(function() {
        var $chevron = $(this).find('.chevron');                
        $chevron.toggleClass("down up");
    });
});
```

Then for CSS, set the classes to the correct chevron image:

```
.chevron.up { background-image('images/up.png'); }
.chevron.down { background-image('images/down.png'); }
```

Comment: What if I wanted to have an up and down class toggle. But start with it down. Right now it's putting the up outside of the span.

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer.  You can add `.down` to all of them on the page load by using `$(".section a .chevron").addClass('down');`